# ReactJS changing variable doesn't re-render

Tags: reactjs, prismic.io

Below is the code that pulls data from Prismic.io and renders it as a masonry.
The issue is with filter() function. When I try to remove some items from cases, it does not render again. What should I do? I tried using useEffect() and useRef()

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

import '../../components/style/caseStudyContainer.scss'
import arrowImage from "../../components/images/ic_arrow_down_white_small.svg"
import iconPhone from "../images/ic_phone_white.svg";
import iconMail from "../images/ic_mail_white.svg";
import shape3img from "../../components/images/shapes/new/shape09-min.jpeg";
import shape5img from "../../components/images/shapes/new/shape07-min.jpeg";
import shape10img from "../../components/images/shapes/new/shape13-min.jpeg";

import { gsap } from 'gsap';
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";
import {useTranslation} from "react-i18next";
import {Client} from "../../utilities/prismicHelpers";
import Prismic from "@prismicio/client";

function CaseStudyPageContainer() {
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

    const url = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();

    useEffect(() => {

        console.log(`You changed the page to: ${url}`)
        if (window.location.href.indexOf('news') > 0) {
            document.querySelector(".news-link-menu").classList.add("active");
        }

    }, [url]);

    const {t, i18n} = useTranslation();

    let isGerman;
    let langStr;

    if (i18n.language=='en') {
        isGerman = false;
        langStr = 'en-US';
    }
    else {
        langStr = 'de-De';
        isGerman = true;
    }

    //const [doc, setDocData] = React.useState([]);
    const doc = useRef([]);
    const [docClone, setDocCloneData] = React.useState([]);
    const [docDe, setDocDataDe] = React.useState(null);

    let categories;
    let solutions = [];

    if(isGerman) {
        let i, index;
        for(i in solutionsDe) {
            for(index = 0; index<solutionsDe[i].length;index++) {
                solutions.push(solutionsDe[i][index]);
            }
        }
        categories = categoriesDe;
    } else {
        let i, index;
        for(i in solutionsEn) {
            for(index = 0; index<solutionsEn[i].length;index++) {
                solutions.push(solutionsEn[i][index]);
            }
        }
        categories = categoriesEn;
    }

    console.log('solutions', solutions);

    const handleChange = e => {
    }

    const [categorySelected, solutionSelected, setSelected] = React.useState("All");
    //await Client.getByUID('case_article_post','under-armour-en', {}) fetch by id, todo: delete this after
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {

            const response = await Client.getByUID('case_list', 'cases',
                { lang : langStr },
            );
            if (response) {
                //setDocData(response);
                doc.current = response;
                setDocCloneData(response);
            }
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    function filter(event) {
        let val = event.target.value;
        let i;
        let data = [];
        for(i in doc.current.data.cases) {
            console.log('filter ', val, doc.current.data.cases[i].branch);
            if(doc.current.data.cases[i].branch == val) {
                doc.current.data.cases.push(doc.current.data.cases[i]);
            }
        }
        doc.current = {data: {cases: []}};
        doc.current = doc.current;
    }

    function getWindowDimensions() {
        const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
        return {
            width,
            height
        };
    }

    const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState(getWindowDimensions());

    console.log('data', doc);

    return (
        doc.current ?
            (
                <div>
                    {windowDimensions.width > 767 ?

                        (<div className="caseStudyPageContainer">
                            <div className="sectionTopJobs">
                                <div className="animationJobsRight">
                                    <img src={shape3img} alt="" style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="container-fluid"
                                     style={{zIndex: '3', position: 'relative', padding: '0px'}}>
                                    <div className="row pt-filter">
                                        <div className="col-12 offset-lg-1 col-lg-11">
                                            <h1 className="PageTitle">{t('caseStudyPageTitle')}</h1>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-12 offset-lg-1 col-lg-11">
                                            <div className="PageDescription">{t('caseStudyPageDescription')}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="row filtersContainerJobs">
                                        <div className="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                            <div className="row">
                                                <div className="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                                    <label htmlFor="">{t('Industry')}</label>
                                                    <select onChange={filter} style={{backgroundImage: `url(${arrowImage})`}}>
                                                        {/*onChange={e => handleChangeLocation(e)} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${arrowImage})` }}>*/}
                                                        {categories.map(category =>
                                                            <option key={category} value={category}>{category}</option>
                                                        )}
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>

                                                <div className="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                                    <label htmlFor="">{t('Solutions')}</label>
                                                    <select style={{backgroundImage: `url(${arrowImage})`}}>
                                                        {/*onChange={e => handleChangeLocation(e)} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${arrowImage})` }}>*/}
                                                        {solutions.map(category =>
                                                            <option key={category} value={category}>{category}</option>
                                                        )}
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div style={{height: '800px', padding: '0px', margin: '0px'}}>

                                            <div style={{height: '100%', float: 'left', width: '66.66%'}}>

                                                <div style={{height: '66.66%', width: '100%'}}>

                                                    <div style={{float: 'left', width: '50%', height: '100%'}}>

                                                        <div className={`card-container`} style={{
                                                            width: 'calc(100% - 8px)',
                                                            height: 'calc(50% - 6px)',
                                                            margin: '4px',
                                                            position: 'relative',
                                                            backgroundSize: 'cover',
                                                            backgroundImage: 'url(' + (typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[0] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[0].case_image.url : '') : '') + ')'
                                                        }}>
                                                            <div className="card-title">
                                                                {(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[0] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[0].case_title[0].text : '') : '')}
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className={`card-info`}>
                                                                <h4>{(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[0] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[0].case_title[0].text : '') : '')}</h4>
                                                                <p>{(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[0] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[0].case_description[0].text : '') : '')}</p>
                                                                <a href={`${(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[0] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[0].case_link : '') : '')}`}
                                                                   className="btn--inverted--solid btn--regular">View
                                                                    case</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div className={`card-container`} style={{
                                                            width: 'calc(100% - 8px)',
                                                            height: 'calc(50% - 6px)',
                                                            position: 'relative',
                                                            margin: '4px',
                                                            backgroundSize: 'cover',
                                                            backgroundImage: 'url(' + (typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[1] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[1].case_image.url : '') : '') + ')'
                                                        }}>
                                                            <div className="card-title">
                                                                {(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[1] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[1].case_title[0].text : '') : '')}
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className={`card-info`}>
                                                                <h4>{(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[1] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[1].case_title[0].text : '') : '')}</h4>
                                                                <p>{(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[1] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[1].case_description[0].text : '') : '')}</p>
                                                                <a href={(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[1] : '')}
                                                                   className="btn--inverted--solid btn--regular">View
                                                                    case</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>

                                                    <div className={`card-container`} style={{
                                                        float: 'left',
                                                        width: 'calc(50% - 8px)',
                                                        height: 'calc(100% - 8px)',
                                                        position: 'relative',
                                                        margin: '4px',
                                                        backgroundPosition: 'center center',
                                                        backgroundSize: 'cover',
                                                        backgroundImage: 'url(' + (typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[2] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[2].case_image.url : '') : '') + ')'
                                                    }}>
                                                        <div className="card-title">
                                                            {(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[2] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[2].case_title[0].text : '') : '')}
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div className={`card-info`}>
                                                            <h4>{(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[2] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[2].case_title[0].text : '') : '')}</h4>
                                                            <p>{(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[2] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[2].case_description[0].text : '') : '')}</p>
                                                            <a href={(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? '' : '')}
                                                               className="btn--inverted--solid btn--regular">View
                                                                case</a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>

                                                <div className={`card-container`} style={{
                                                    width: 'calc(100% - 4px)',
                                                    height: 'calc(33.33% - 4px)',
                                                    position: 'relative',
                                                    margin: '2px',
                                                    backgroundSize: 'cover',
                                                    backgroundImage: 'url(' + (typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[3] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[3].case_image.url : '') : '') + ')'
                                                }}>
                                                    <div className={`card-info`}>
                                                        <h4>{(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[3] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[3].case_title[0].text : '') : '')}</h4>
                                                        <p>{(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[3] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[3].case_description[0].text : '') : '')}</p>
                                                        <a href={(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[3] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[3].case_link : '') : '')}
                                                           className="btn--inverted--solid btn--regular">View case</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                            <div style={{width: '33.33%', float: 'left', height: '100%'}}>
                                                <div className={`card-container`} style={{
                                                    height: 'calc(33.33% - 4px)',
                                                    width: 'calc(100% - 4px)',
                                                    position: 'relative',
                                                    margin: '2px',
                                                    backgroundSize: 'cover',
                                                    backgroundImage: 'url(' + (typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[4] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[4].case_image.url : '') : '') + ')'
                                                }}>
                                                    <div className={`card-info`}>
                                                        <h4>{(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[4] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[4].case_title[0].text : '') : '')}</h4>
                                                        <p>{(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[4] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[4].case_description[0].text : '') : '')}</p>
                                                        <a href={(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[4] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[4].case_link : '') : '')}
                                                           className="btn--inverted--solid btn--regular">View case</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div className={`card-container`} style={{
                                                    height: 'calc(66.66% - 4px)',
                                                    width: 'calc(100% - 4px)',
                                                    position: 'relative',
                                                    margin: '2px',
                                                    backgroundSize: 'cover',
                                                    backgroundImage: 'url(' + (typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[5] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[5].case_image.url : '') : '') + ')'
                                                }}>
                                                    <div className={`card-info`}>
                                                        <h4>{(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[5] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[5].case_title[0].text : '') : '')}</h4>
                                                        <p>{(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[5] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[5].case_description[0].text : '') : '')}</p>
                                                        <a href={(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[5] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[5].case_link : '') : '')}
                                                           className="btn--inverted--solid btn--regular">View case</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                        <div style={{
                                            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                            height: '600px',
                                            padding: '0px',
                                            margin: '0px'
                                        }}>
                                            <div className={`card-container`} style={{
                                                margin: '4px',
                                                float: 'left',
                                                width: 'calc(33.33% - 8px)',
                                                height: 'calc(100% - 8px)',
                                                position: 'relative',
                                                backgroundSize: 'cover',
                                                backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                                                backgroundImage: 'url(' + (typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[6] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[6].case_image.url : '') : '') + ')'
                                            }}>
                                                <div className={`card-info`}>
                                                    <h4>{(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[6] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[6].case_title[0].text : '') : '')}</h4>
                                                    <p>{(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[6] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[6].case_description[0].text : '') : '')}</p>
                                                    <a href={(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[6] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[6].case_link : '') : '')}
                                                       className="btn--inverted--solid btn--regular">View case</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div style={{float: 'left', width: '66.66%', height: '100%'}}>

                                                <div style={{
                                                    margin: '4px',
                                                    width: 'calc(100% - 6px)',
                                                    height: 'calc(100% - 8px)',
                                                    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                                                    backgroundSize: 'cover',
                                                    backgroundImage: 'url(' + (typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[7] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[7].case_image.url : '') : '') + ')'
                                                }}>
                                                    <div className="card-container"
                                                         style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', position: 'relative'}}>
                                                        <div className={`card-info`}>
                                                            <h4>{(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[7] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[7].case_title[0].text : '') : '')}</h4>
                                                            <p>{(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[7] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[7].case_description[0].text : '') : '')}</p>
                                                            <a href={(typeof doc.current.data != 'undefined' ? (typeof doc.current.data.cases[7] != 'undefined' ? doc.current.data.cases[7].case_link : '') : '')}
                                                               className="btn--inverted--solid btn--regular">View case</a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div className="animationCaseStudyLeft">
                                    <img src={shape5img} alt="" style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="shapesJobsPageKontakttrigger"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="shapesJobsPagetrigger"></div>


                        </div>) :

                        (<div className="caseStudyPageContainer">
                            <div className="sectionTopJobs">
                                <div className="animationJobsRight">
                                    <img src={shape3img} alt="" style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="container"
                                     style={{zIndex: '3', position: 'relative', padding: '0px !important'}}>
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col-12 offset-lg-1 col-lg-11">
                                            <h1 className="PageTitle">{t('caseStudyPageTitle')}</h1>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-12 offset-lg-1 col-lg-11">
                                            <div className="PageDescription">{t('caseStudyPageDescription')}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                            <div className="row">
                                                <div className="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                                    <label htmlFor="">{t('Industry')}</label>
                                                    <select style={{backgroundImage: `url(${arrowImage})`}}>
                                                        {/*onChange={e => handleChangeLocation(e)} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${arrowImage})` }}>*/}
                                                        {categories.map(category =>
                                                            <option key={category} value={category}>{category}</option>
                                                        )}
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>

                                                <div className="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                                    <label htmlFor="">{t('Solutions')}</label>
                                                    <select style={{backgroundImage: `url(${arrowImage})`}}>
                                                        {/*onChange={e => handleChangeLocation(e)} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${arrowImage})` }}>*/}
                                                        {solutions.map(category =>
                                                            <option key={category} value={category}>{category}</option>
                                                        )}
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="row">
                                        <a href={"/" + i18n.language + "/page/xing"}>
                                            <div className="col-12 case-card" style={{
                                                margin: '4px',
                                                height: '243px',
                                                backgroundSize: 'cover',
                                                backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                                                backgroundImage: 'url(' + (doc.length > 0 ? doc[0].data.case_image_desktop.url : '') + ')'
                                            }}>
                                                <h4>{(doc.length > 0 ? doc[0].data.title[0].text : '')}</h4>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>                            
                                </div>

                                <div className="animationCaseStudyLeft">
                                    <img src={shape5img} alt="" style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="shapesJobsPageKontakttrigger"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="shapesJobsPagetrigger"></div>


                        </div>)
                    }
                </div>
            )
            : ('Loading')
    );
}

export default CaseStudyPageContainer;
```

Below is the code that pulls data from Prismic.io and renders it as a masonry.
The issue is with filter() function. When I try to remove some items from cases, it does not render again. What should I do? I tried using useEffect() and useRef()

Comment: can you try `onChange={ () => filter(); }`?

Comment: Where in that function are you updating state?  Where are you even tracking state?  Where in that function are you updating state?  Where are you even tracking state?

Answer (score 1):

I think it does not re-render, because you are not changing the state of `doc` anywhere.
You should have something like:

```
const [doc, setDoc] = useState(<defaultValueHere>);
```

and then in the `filter()` function, you should invoke the setter, once you have the new value for `doc`:

```
function filter() {
   /* 
      do your logic here
      and collect the new value in a separate variable, 
      called newDoc
   */
   const newDoc = ...;
   /*
     finally, pass the new value to the setDoc function 
     and this will trigger re-rendering
   */
   setDoc(newDoc);
}
```

Comment: Given this function: `code` function filter(event) {
        let val = event.target.value;
        let i;
        let data = doc;
        data.data.cases = [];
        for(i in docClone.data.cases) {
            if(doc.data.cases[i].branch == val) {
                data.data.cases.push(docClone.data.cases[i]);
            }
        }

        setDocData(data);
    } It will remove data from cases from all variables. I think it's passed by memory reference. @konstantin-yovkov